# Use of possibly-uninitialized variable after returning

Tags: function, http, parsing, rust, initialization

I have this function `parse` to parse a HTTP request string. I declare an uninitialized variable `method` then later on in the `match` statement, I assign it the value `GET` or I return from the function with an error.

I would think that upon returning `Ok`, the method field would be either populated or the function would return an error before that point, yet the compiler tells me that this is not the case:

```
error[E0381]: use of possibly-uninitialized variable: `method`
    Ok(HttpRequest { s_addr: s_addr, method, scheme: RequestScheme::HTTP })
                                     ^^^^^^ use of possibly-uninitialized `method`
```

```
pub fn parse(request_string: String, s_addr: SocketAddr) -> Result<HttpRequest, HttpError> {
    let mut method: HttpMethod;
    for element in request_string.split(" ") {
        method = match element {
            "GET" => HttpMethod::GET,
            _ => { 
                eprintln!("Couldn't parse word : {}", element); 
                return Err(HttpError::ParseError);
            },
        }
    }
    Ok(HttpRequest { s_addr: s_addr, method, scheme: RequestScheme::HTTP })
}
```

Comment: What if the `for` loop has 0 iterations?

Comment: @mkrieger1 Might add: That won't happen with `split`, but the part of Rust that decides whether a variable is live or not doesn't know anything about how iterators work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [@mkrieger1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4621513/mkrieger1) points out:

> What if the `for` loop has 0 iterations?

`String`'s `split` function never returns an empty iterator, so consider using an `Option<T>`, then unwrapping the value.

```rust
let mut method: Option<HttpMethod> = None;

for element in request_string.split(" ") {
    if element != "GET" {
        eprintln!("Couldn't parse word : {}", element); 
        return Err(HttpError::ParseError);
    }
    method.insert(HttpMethod::Get);
}

Ok(HttpRequest { s_addr, method: method.unwrap(), scheme: RequestScheme::HTTP})
```

Or, in your case you can just avoid a variable all together.

```rust
for element in request_string.split(" ") {
    if element != "GET" {
        eprintln!("Couldn't parse word : {}", element); 
        return Err(HttpError::ParseError);
    }
}
Ok(HttpRequest { s_addr, method: HttpMethod::Get, scheme: RequestScheme::HTTP})
```

Comment: Don't use `insert()` if you don't need the returned value. Use a simple assignment: `method = Some(HttpMethod::Get)`.